# css attribute value to have the same value as another css attribute value multiplied by 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve this effect using jQuery and it has been giving me a bit of trouble:

I would like a css attribute value to have the same value as another css attribute value multiplied by 2.

In more detail, I would like a margin-left value which is set as a percentage to have the same value as a margin-top value multiplied by 2.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you should read about LESS CSS.. That will make it possible to handle variables and much more.. :)

Comment: Also, check out CSS `calc()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Is margin-top set in pixels or percentage as well?

Comment: LESS or SASS is the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like denlau says, you should use LESS, or like JoshC says, use the CSS3 property calc(). But in jQuery, you could use:

```js
var element = $('#element'),
  marginTop = parseFloat(element.css('marginTop'));

element.css('marginLeft', 2*marginTop);
```

Check the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/tJJga/).

Comment: Not exactly... that would change the style attached to #element, but wouldn't change the css value of the underlying style.

Comment: You want to edit in CSS, not in jQuery so. For this, you could use LESS or calc().

Comment: Who are you talking to? If you type here, I'm the only one getting notified.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was user2812034 who was commenting. But I didn't understand your comment. I think is the approach he is seeking.

Comment: I mean if you `.css` an element, the styles will be attached to the element. The actual style (e.g. `#element { something }`) is not changed.

Comment: Exactly, is an inline style. To change in CSS, only if using LESS or calc(), but in the question, he said "I am trying to achieve this effect using jQuery".